# How to comment and uncomment code in a contextmenu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a contextmenu that shows on right-click using a mousedown event and 2 of my list for contextmenu are comment and uncomment with this code:

```
private void CommentMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtb.SelectedText = "//" + rtb.SelectedText;
        lb.Hide();
    }

    private void UnCommentMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtb.SelectedText = rtb.SelectedText.Replace("//", "");
        lb.Hide();
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

but for comment when I select all and there's diff rows of text (selectall) the output was:

[image]

but I should be like:

[image]

(Don't mind the highlighting just I want the // before the text).

How can I add // before diff rows of text? Also for uncomment is my code enough? Or is there more/better code for that?

### Edit

```
void Parse()
    {
        String inputLanguage = "\n";

        // Foreach line in input,
        // identify key words and format them when adding to the rich text box.
        Regex r = new Regex("\\n");
        String[] lines = r.Split(inputLanguage);
        foreach (string l in lines)
        {
            ParseLine(l);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should also decide what to do if the user select text from the middle of a line. I suppose you would like to comment the line from its beginning anyway (that's what Visual does with Ctrl+K,C), so you should probably look for the last NewLine preceding the SelectedText first.

Comment: Might want to rename `inputLanguage` to something like `newlineChar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only adding '//' to the start of the text.

You need to parse the selected text for a new line char and then prepend a '//' to the start of each line.

String Builder is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), it's in System.Text

something like this:

```
private void CommentMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sw = new StringBuilder();

    string line;
    StringReader rdr = new StringReader(rtb.SelectedText);
    line = rdr.ReadLine();
    while(line != null)
    {
            sw.AppendLine(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) ? "//" : "" + line);
            line= rdr.ReadLine();
    }
    rtb.SelectedText = sw.ToString();
    lb.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Each line containing code by the looks of it. That's not much extra parsing.

Comment: I think @Preet is right. You can do that with simple parsing.

Comment: I'd change it to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) ? "//" : ""` to only comment lines with code.

Comment: sir @PreetSangha how can i add stringwriter? it cant be call

Comment: the .AppendLine(IsNullOrWhitePace(line) not recognize sir

Comment: with 2errors : the name 'isnullorwhitepace' does not exist and 'System.IO.StringWriter' does not contain a definition for 'AppendLine' and no expansion method ..................................'

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is replace the newline with "//"
so try this

```
rtb.SelectedText = "//" + rtb.SelectedText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, System.Environment.NewLine + "//")
```

Comment: lol im working on a code-editor sir . im not on actual editor

Comment: ops yeaa i noticed soon as i submit it. wrote the alternative solution now. you guys reply too fast :(

Comment: String = rtb.SelectedText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, System.Environment.NewLine + "//"); ? is this right sir? if it is theres a 1error 'string' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: Sorry i didn't make it clear, so your code should look something like this rtb.SelectedText = "//" + rtb.SelectedText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, System.Environment.NewLine + "//"), Code updated

Comment: same result sir .only the 1st text got the // and the other row doesnt :/

Comment: hmmm sorry I'm not sure what's happening, but I've created the winform app prototype and seems to be working. but it seems "\n" is working for you? What System.Environment.NewLine is doing is it checks what environment you in and return the new line code in your environemnt. "\r\n" --> most of the windows environment. "\n" --> is unix enivroment. Sorry i couldn't be much help :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to break it out by line and add "//" to the beginning of each.  Right now you're just adding "//" to be beginning of a single string composed of every line concatenated (hence the single "//").

Answer (score 0):

First split each line. Then add // to the start of each line.

```
string[] lines = selected.Split('/n', '/r');
foreach (string l in lines)
{
    ParseLine(l);
}
```

Add to these lines and append them. The appended string is to be replaced with the selected text.

***EDIT:***

Commenting:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string source = "comment me" + Environment.NewLine + "line two.";
        string[] lines = source.Split('\r', '\n');
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("//" + line);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
// comment me
// line two.
```

Online snippet: http://ideone.com/sGJNzr

Uncommenting:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string source = "//uncomment me" + Environment.NewLine + "//line two.";
        string[] lines = source.Split('\r', '\n');
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line.Replace("//", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
uncomment me
line two.
```

Online snippet: http://ideone.com/roY0AK

You need to set `source` to `rtb.SelectedText`

Comment: You can do that but all lines could have a `//` even without a code.

Comment: sir where can iadd those code? i already have the Parse code ill edit my question .

Comment: @Elegiac edited the answer. Put the code sample in the parse method.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati ok sir ill try sec

Comment: @Elegiac I've edited the answer with a working solution. Hope you can adapt it now.